# Power loss due to eddy currents

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, units

I am curious about estimating power losses due to eddy currents. Looking on Wikipedia I find an expression for [power dissipation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current#Power_dissipation_of_eddy_currents) under limited circumstances,
$$
P = \frac{\pi^2 B^2 d^2 f^2}{6k\rho D}
$$
where $P$ is the power in watts per kilogram, $B$ is the peak field, $d$ is the thickness of the conductor, $f$ is the frequency, $k\sim1$ is a dimensionless constant which depends on the geometry, $\rho$ is the resistivity, and $D$ is the mass density.

However, I can't make the units work out. The tricky ones are usually the electromagnetic units.  From the Lorentz force $\vec F = q\vec v\times\vec B$ I find
$$
\mathrm{
1\,T = 1 \frac{N\cdot s}{C\cdot m}
}.
$$
From Ohm's law $V=IR$,
$$
\mathrm{
1\,\Omega = 1\,\frac{V}{A} = 1\,\frac{N\cdot s}{C^2}
},
$$
and the dimension of $\rho$ is $\mathrm{\Omega\cdot m}$.

So the dimensions of ratio $P$ should be
\begin{align*}
\left[ B^2 (d\,f)^2 \rho^{-1} D^{-1} \right]
&=
\mathrm{
\left( \frac{N\cdot s}{C\cdot m} \right)^2
\left( \frac ms \right)^2
\left( \frac{C^2}{N\cdot s\cdot m} \right)
\left( \frac{m^3}{kg} \right)
}\\\
&=
\mathrm{
\left( \frac{N^2}{C^2} \right)
\left( \frac{C^2}{N\cdot s\cdot m} \right)
\left( \frac{m^3}{kg} \right)
}\\
&=
\mathrm{
\left( \frac{N}{m\cdot s} \right)
\left( \frac{m^3}{kg} \right)
}
= 
\mathrm{
\frac{N\cdot m^2}{s\cdot kg} = \frac{W\cdot m}{kg}
}
\end{align*}
This is different from the stated units of $\mathrm{W/kg}$. Am I making some stupid mistake? Is the formula wrong? What's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good practice to double check Wikipedia, but in this case Wikipedia is right. Those E&M units are tricky. From

$F=Eq$ we get that $V=\frac{N \cdot m}{C}$ So $\Omega = \frac{N \cdot s \cdot m}{C^2}$ which solves your problem.

Comment: I usually remember that $\mathrm{V = J/C}$ relates potential and potential energy. I got my wires crossed and wrote it the same wrong way until it looked right. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in the above: "From Ohm's law V=IR", 
Ω=V/A=(J/C)/(C/sec)=(Nm/C)/(C/sec)=N*m*sec/C*C, not N*sec/C*C

Comment: Welcome to Physics! This seems to be a duplicate of the accepted answer, except the accepted answer *argues* that the question used the wrong definition of the volt, while this answer just asserts so.