# Shooting a bullet into an MRI

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

What happens, if one shoots a bullet into an MRI system? Is there any chance to fully stop the bullet?

Boundary condifitions:

Consider an MRI machine with a reasonalby strong magnetic field (~3T) and tunable gradient coils. Furthermore, suppose we have a standard gun and bullet to shoot into the field of the machine.

Can we find a trajectory, that stops the bullet from leaving the MRI system?

For example, stopping it, reversing it, leading it on a circular path inside the machine etc. etc.?

**Update:** The stationary field inside the MRI machine seems to be a bad candidate, as it follows the centerline in a parallel fashion. So, is there any chance of eddy currents inside the bullet that help slowing it down? I found the x-y-gradient fields in a typical MRI system, the peak gradient is about 35-45 mT/m.The slew rate, which is defined as peak gradient over rise time can reach up to 200 T/m/s.

Answer (score 2):

**New Version** (as I had my doubts on the orders of magnetude...and it turned out that I made a mistake)

To simplify things I assume:

1. velocity $v=1000\; \mathrm m /\mathrm s$
2. perfectly conducting bullet
3. density of $\rho=10000\; \mathrm{kg}/\mathrm{m}^3$
4. A $B_\mathrm{max}=5\;\mathrm T$ and constant gradient of $B'=5\;\mathrm{T}/\mathrm{m}$

If the bullet is a considered a single winding solenoid field inside is

$$B=\mu_0 \lambda(x),$$
where $\lambda$ is the surface charge density. The dipole moment is
$$P=\mu_0 A I=\mu_0 V \lambda,$$
with current $I=l\lambda$,length $l$, area $A$, and Volume $V$. In this geometry the force on the dipole is
$$F(x)=\frac{P}{\mu_0} \frac{\mathrm d B}{\mathrm d x}=\frac{\mu_0 V \lambda}{\mu_0} B'=\frac{V B(x)}{\mu_0} B'$$
and as $B(x)=xB'$,i.e. constant gradient
$$F(x)=V\frac{(B')^2}{\mu_0}x$$
the integrated energy then is
$$E(x)=V\frac{(B')^2}{\mu_0}\frac{x^2}{2}$$
and we should have 
$$V\frac{(B')^2}{\mu_0}\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac 1 2 m v^2 = \frac{\rho V}{2}v^2$$
hence
$$\frac{(B')^2}{\mu_0}x^2=\rho v^2$$
i.e.
$$x=\frac{v}{B'}\sqrt{\mu_0 \rho},$$
which in our case is $22\;\mathrm m$ and not one.

Again looking at energy we could try to figure out the speed reduction
$$v=\sqrt{v_0^2-\frac{(B')^2}{\rho \mu_0}x^2}$$
which is insignificant. Moreover I guess that there are no reasonable $B'$ and $\rho$ to make it work. But you could probably stop a $150\;\mathrm m/\mathrm s$  aluminum arrow shot by an archer.

I hope that I have my math correct now.

Comment: You might state the equations you have used and cite their sources. This is a surprising result - I shouldn't have thought it would make such a difference to such a body - even in the idealized case you have investigated.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance I agree, didn't think I would get this results when I started. I'll try to update according to your request/suggestion

Comment: Have to check if I messed up some orders of magnitude.....

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance it turned out there was a mistake. I hope my new results are correct now. Also fits better with my intuition

Comment: I'm wondering how you derive B(x). First, the constant B-field inside an MRI machine is parallel to the middle axis in the (iso-)center of the MRI, so the bullet is travelling along the field lines. Second, don't we have to consider the slew rate of the gradient field? These can easily go up to 200T/m/s. I'll update my question with these maximum values.

Comment: @Dschoni I think the switching rate of the magnet as source of induction , and therefore Eddy currents, is negligible compared to the change of field when the bullet enters the field with high speed. 
My $x$ is actually the magnet axis.

Comment: I just found the calculation for the eddy currents here http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/238344/40371 . They say there, that shooting a bullet along the field lines doesn't introduce eddy currents. But does it excert force on the dipol no matter the direction?

Comment: @Dschoni Well, did not read all of it, but what I can say is:If by field line you mean along constant field, this is true. This is why you cannot stop it inside a long solenoid. Here the field is almost constant, meaning that the $dB/dt$ as caused by  the movement of the bullet is basically zero. Therefore no Eddy currents and no deceleration. If you however consider the penetration of the solenoid things change. You have significant $dB/dt$, Colleges of mine played with it, tipping over heavy aluminum sheets in an MRI gradient, observing how they fall in slow motion.

Comment: I so want to meet your colleges. We try to convince our head of departement to actually allow us to shoot bullets into an MRI with gradient synced to the bullet speed ;)

Comment: @Dschoni Good luck with that. But to emphasize once again. I do not think that the MRI gradient field, required for imaging with spacial resolution is of importance. In my opinion it is the gradient of the static field the bullet sees when entering the MRI. Looking [here](https://practicalfmri.blogspot.de/2012/09/intense-stray-static-magnetic-field.html), I amtalking about the region in the dashed box, where you have an field increase of $2.5$ T/m. With a $500$ m/s bullet this gives $dB/dt=1250$ T/s.

Comment: I see, you are talking about the field outside of the core. And you are absolutely correct with that. So but in that case, the calculation in the linked answer should hold true as the bullet is crossing these lines outside the core in perpendicular fashion. And if so, I wonder why they arrive at 0.9T being enough to stop a bullet in 1m.

Comment: In case of Eddy current brakes it is slightly different. There the field is assumed to changed from 0 to max within your moving distance. Note that they talk about a constant field not a gradient. In case of the bullet moving into this constant field that would virtually mean something like 1 T per 2 cm, which is a 50 T/m gradient. Second, my physics is somewhat different. In Eddy current brakes the movement is perpendicular to the field. I assume that the stopping is due to the induced dipole repelling the MRI static field.